# Ember.js on the server

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I'm developing a very dynamic web application via ember.js. The client-side communicates with a server-side JSON API. A user can make various choices and see diced & filtered data from all kinds of perspectives, where all of this data is brought from said API.

Thing is, I also need to generate static pages (that Google can understand) from the same data. These static pages represent pre-defined views and don't allow much interaction; they are meant to serve as landing pages for users arriving from search engines.

Naturally, I'd like to reuse as much as I can from my dynamic web application to generate these static pages, so the natural direction I thought of going for is implementing a server-side module to render these pages which would reuse as much as possible of my Ember.js views & code.

However - I can't find any material on that. Ember's docs say "Although it is possible to use Ember.js on the server side, that is beyond the scope of this guide."

Can anyone point out what would be possible to reuse on the server-end, and best practices  for designing the app in a way to enable maximal such reuse?

Of course, if you think my thinking here doesn't make sense, I'd be glad to hear this (and  why) too :-)

Thanks!
C.

Comment: Enabling `Ember.js` on `Node.js` is currently discussed and being worked on in https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/769 and https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/771.

Comment: @pangratz Thanks! Will now take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) - Ember's templating engine - does run on the server (at least under Node.js). I've used it in my own projects.

When serving an HTTP request for a page, you could quite possibly use your existing templates: pull the relevant data from the DB, massage it into a JSON object, feed it to handlebars along with the right template, then send the result to the client.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that's the least I could do; still wondering if there's more :)

Comment: Funny I cam across this. I had to do exactly this. I'm curious if you could update us on the path you took.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not just about the handlebars. If you want to have your app fully crawleble you need also other things have server-side handled - actions, events, etc ...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://phantomjs.org/
You could use it to render the pages on the server and return a plain html version.

You have to make it follow googles ajax crawling guides: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started